# Is it ok to have GWT for the admin and to choose another java framework for the website?

Tags: google-app-engine, frameworks, web

My project has a website (frontend) and an admin (backend).

I would like to do the whole project (front/back-end) with GWT, but I have some reason to have my website running without javascript.

These reasons are :

- portability on mobile phone.
- a best practice recommend to have a website running without js.

So I can t do the website with GWT...and I also need a MVC, internationalization...and other stuff existing in a classical web framework. I will develop my application on **google app engine**.

Does it make sense to use 2 frameworks (GWT for the admin and Spring MVC for the website) ?

Thanks you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not uncommon to use different tools and frameworks for internal admin tools and external websites. In many places I have worked admin tools have been desktop based because they are quicker to develop.

so, if it works for you, go for it!

Comment: ok, and could I do the frontend in Python and the backend in JAva ?

Comment: @nzaero You could, by using different major version numbers, but why on earth would you?

Comment: Ok : I would have prefered to use python for its 'elegant syntax'...but there is not a gwt-like framework in python (except pyjama which not comparable because of the less developement). I could use python+javascript, but I do not want to learn to program (and learn) javascript (I do not want to complexify the code with to much languages. I would have prefered to have a version of the website working in pure html+css (I heard that it is a best practice).

Comment: I would have prefered to have a version of the website working in pure html+css (I heard that it is a best practice) but I need at least a MVC pattern and maybe other stuff provided by Play, Spring MVC etc... but I would also avoid to waste to much time learning to many frameworks. OK, so I did my choice, I will use GWTP, for the website and the admin.

Comment: I know hope that the website code will be portable on mobile phone and Tablet, will be able to be crawled by all search engine (not just google), and that it will run fastly. I am not well experienter, and I have serious headackes but choosing the right technologies, frameworks etc..